# Android OpenCv : unexpected FPS decrease over time on Nexus 7

Tags: java, android, opencv, frame-rate, javacameraview

since two days i try to detect the root of a very strange behaviour with my OpenCV-Application. So maybe the you guys could help me to solve this problem.

I am using the OpenCv 3.4 which i compiled from source to support contrib modules.
My App uses JavaCameraView-class to receive frames and extract the Mat data out of it for further processing. 
It works very well with 25 - 30 FPS on my Samsung Galaxy S8 without FPS decrease over time. There the FPS only depends on the lighting situation.

But on my Nexus 7, which i need for my customer to work on, the behaviour is quite different. 
I get ~25 FPS at beginning when the JavaCamera got opened. After that it has a FPS decrease rate of ~1 FPS every ~2 minutes. ~30 minutes later my App only has ~7FPS which is not acceptable for my needs. 
i already opened an issue in case that its a Bug inside. You can look there for more information: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11229

Do you know if thats a well known behaviour and if there is some kind of solution for that? 
I am afraid that it could be a hardware or OS side problem but it could be a memory allocation problem or something too 
Since 2 days I try to figure out whats wrong here. 
Thanks in advance for your help dudes

Comment: That's probably throttling, check for CPU usage after a while.

Comment: I did a bit of research about throttling. It's a possibility but I can't find no approach to avoid this. Do you know what we can do or is it a fixed OS side problem?

Comment: It's hardware limitations, vendors do that in order to prolong device life, so there is nothing you can do to stop that. What you should do is to limit CPU usage for your app and think if user would really need to use camera in your app for more than a minute (that sounds unlikely). If you indeed need to do a lot of heavy processing on your device - think about moving from opencv solution to combination of gles and opencv which would not only improve fps but also reduce cpu usage.